# Example of structured xqueue freeRTOS

Tags: multithreading, queue, esp32, freertos

I'm coming to you because I'm desperate about my problem. I've already made a previous post ([xQueue ESP32 can't send two command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66797899/xqueue-esp32-cant-send-two-command)) but I've tried but I don't have the expected result.

Result :

len : -1184515756

data :

I also tried these two tutorials but still nothing works...
https://freertos.org/a00018.html
https://controllerstech.com/freertos-tutorial-5-using-queue/

After several tries without really understanding how I got something almost working except I end up with a Guru Err Load Prohibited.

Code :

```
void app_main() {

/* Create the queue used to send complete struct message structures. */
    uart_queue = xQueueCreate(20, sizeof(struct message));
    xMutexUart = xSemaphoreCreateMutex();
   
    ....

struct message *ptx_msg =pvPortMalloc(sizeof (struct message));
    //Set Channel
    sprintf(ptx_msg->cmd,"%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",0x01, 0x02, 0x10, 0x21, 0x02, 0x10, 0x02, 0x14, 0x2D, 0x02, 0x10, 0x02, 0x10, 0x02, 0x18, 0x02, 0x10, 0x03);
    ptx_msg->len = strlen(ptx_msg->cmd);
    printf("len : %d\n", ptx_msg->len);
            for(int i=0;i<ptx_msg->len;i++){
                printf("%02x ",ptx_msg->cmd[i]);
            }
    xSemaphoreTake(xMutexUart, portMAX_DELAY);
    xQueueSend(uart_queue, (void*)&ptx_msg, portMAX_DELAY);
    xSemaphoreGive(xMutexUart);

    //repeat X time

    ....
}
```

```
void vTaskSend( void * pvParameters )
{
    struct message *rx_msg;
    int err;
    while(1){
        xSemaphoreTake(xMutexUart, portMAX_DELAY);
        if (xQueueReceive(uart_queue, &rx_msg, portMAX_DELAY) == pdPASS){
            printf("len : %d\n", rx_msg->len);
            for(int i=0;i<rx_msg->len;i++){
                printf("%02x ",rx_msg->cmd[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            err = uart_write_bytes(uart_num, (const char *)rx_msg->cmd, rx_msg->len); // Write data to UART.
            ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_wait_tx_done(uart_num, 5000)); // wait timeout is 5000 RTOS ticks (TickType_t)
            
            if(err != rx_msg->len){
                printf("Err, not all bytes send : %d/%d\n",err,rx_msg->len);
            }
            vPortFree(rx_msg);  // free the structure memory*/
            vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
            //taskYIELD();
        }
        xSemaphoreGive(xMutexUart);
        vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
    }
}
```

Result :

len : 19

data : 01 02 10 21 02 10 02 14 2d 02 10 02 10 02 18 02 10 03 0a

I would like to correct my problem please!

EDIT :

Here is the code that I have and the result is :

len : 54516257561

data :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <freertos/FreeRTOS.h>
#include <freertos/task.h>
#include <freertos/queue.h>
#include <esp_system.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <driver/uart.h>

#define COMMAND_DEVICE_LIST 0x15
#define COMMAND_STATUS 0x00
#define COMMAND_DESCRIPTION 0x43
#define COMMAND_UNRECOGNIZED 0x11
#define COMMAND_ADDGROUP 0x60
#define COMMAND_BIND 0x30

#define SIZE_TYPE_DEVICE 2
#define SIZE_CLUSTER 2
#define SIZE_SHORT_ADD 2
#define SIZE_IEEE_ADD 8
#define START_DATA 7
#define SIZE_MIN_NB_DEVICE 2

#define CHAR_END_FRAME 0x03
#define CHAR_CONFIG_FRAME 0x02
#define CHAR_VAL_MAX_CONFIG_FRAME 0x10

#define STACK_SIZE 2048

//storage info
struct device{
    char type_id[SIZE_TYPE_DEVICE];
    char manufacturer[32]; //attribute 4
    char name[32]; // attribute 5
    char short_add[SIZE_SHORT_ADD];
    char ieee_add[SIZE_IEEE_ADD];
    char cluster_input[32][SIZE_CLUSTER];
    char cluster_output[32][SIZE_CLUSTER];
};
struct get_device_list{
    int len;
    struct device device[];
}dev_list;

//list device type
char list_device_type[2][SIZE_TYPE_DEVICE]={{0x01,0x0C},{0x08,0x20}};

// Setup UART buffered IO with event queue
const int uart_buffer_size = 2048;
// Queue used to send and receive complete struct message structures. 
QueueHandle_t uart_queue = NULL;
const int uart_num = UART_NUM_2;

struct message{
    char cmd[128];
    int len;
};

SemaphoreHandle_t xMutexUart;

/************************************************CONFIG***********************************************/

/**
 * @brief Configuraiton of UART and set pin that uart use.
 * 
 * @return [int] 0 if is successed
 */
int uart_setup()
{
    uart_config_t uart_config = {
        .baud_rate = 115200,
        .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
        .parity = UART_PARITY_DISABLE,
        .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
        .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_DISABLE
    };
    // Configure UART parameters
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_param_config(uart_num, &uart_config));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_set_pin(UART_NUM_2, 18, 19, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE));
    // Install UART driver using an event queue here
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_driver_install(UART_NUM_2, uart_buffer_size, \
                                        uart_buffer_size, 20, &uart_queue, 0));
    return 0;
}


/************************************************UTILS***********************************************/
int cmdlen(char* cmd){
    int i = 0;
    while(cmd[i]!='\n'){
        i++;
    }
    return i+1;
}


int device_shortadd_compare(char* search_add){
    int res=-1,val=0;
    for(int i=0;i < dev_list.len;i++){
        val = 0;
        for(int l=0;l<SIZE_TYPE_DEVICE;l++){
            if(search_add[l]==dev_list.device[i].short_add[l]){
                val++;
            }
        }
        if(val == 2){
            res=i;
        }
    }
    return res;
}


int parse_translate(char* data,int len,char res[][64]){
    int i=0,j=0,end=0,index=0;
    while(len - j != 0){
        if (data[j]==CHAR_CONFIG_FRAME)
        {
            j++; //skip 02
            data[j]^=0x10; //10xor10=00
            res[end][i-index]= data[j];
            printf("%02x ",res[end][i-index]);
            i++;
                    
        }else if (data[j]==CHAR_END_FRAME)
        {
            res[end][i-index]=data[j];
            res[end][i+1-index]='\n';
            res[end][i+2-index]='\0';
            printf("%02x\n",res[end][i-index]);
            i=i+2;
            index=i;
            end++;
            
        }else{
            res[end][i-index]= data[j];
            printf("%02x ",res[end][i-index]);
            i++;
        }
        j++;
        
    }
    return end;
}


/************************************************COMMUNICATION***********************************************/
/**
 * @brief [Thread]Send commande to Zigbee module by UART
 * 
 */
void vTaskSend( void * pvParameters )
{
    while(1){
        int err;
        struct message rx_msg;
        if (xQueueReceive(uart_queue, &rx_msg, portMAX_DELAY) == pdPASS){
            printf("len : %d\n", rx_msg.len);
            for(int i=0;i< rx_msg.len;i++){
                printf("%02x ", rx_msg.cmd[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            xSemaphoreTake(xMutexUart, portMAX_DELAY);
            err = uart_write_bytes(uart_num, (const char *) rx_msg.cmd,  rx_msg.len); // Write data to UART.
            ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_wait_tx_done(uart_num, 5000)); // wait timeout is 5000 RTOS ticks (TickType_t)
            xSemaphoreGive(xMutexUart);
            if(err !=  rx_msg.len){
                printf("Err, not all bytes send : %d/%d\n",err, rx_msg.len);
            }
            //vPortFree(rx_msg);  // free the structure memory*/
            vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
            //taskYIELD();
        }
        xSemaphoreGive(xMutexUart);
        vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
    }
}

/**
 * @brief [Thread]Read response from UART
 * 
 */
void vTaskRead( void * pvParameters )
{
    char data[512];
    int length = 0;
    while(1){   
        xSemaphoreTake(xMutexUart, portMAX_DELAY);
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_get_buffered_data_len(uart_num, (size_t*)&length));
        length = uart_read_bytes(uart_num, (uint8_t*)data, length, 100);
        xSemaphoreGive(xMutexUart);
        if(length>0){
            printf("[R] message size :  %d\n ",length);
            char res[8][64];
            int nb_cmd=parse_translate(data,length,res);
            for(int i=0;i<nb_cmd;i++){
                switch(res[i][2]){
                    case COMMAND_STATUS:
                        if(res[6]==COMMAND_STATUS){
                            printf("Command status success\n");
                        }
                        break;
                    case COMMAND_DEVICE_LIST:
                        dev_list.len=(cmdlen(res[i])-8)/13;
                        printf("Nb device find : %d\n",dev_list.len);
                        int start = START_DATA; //start of device info in frame
                        for(int j=0;j<dev_list.len;j++){
                            struct device dev;
                            printf("short: ");
                            for(int j=0;j<SIZE_SHORT_ADD;j++){
                                dev.short_add[j] = res[i][start+j];
                                printf("%02x ",dev.short_add[j]);
                            }
                            printf("\n");
                            printf("ieee: ");
                            for(int l=0;l<SIZE_IEEE_ADD;l++){
                                dev.ieee_add[l]=res[i][start+2+l];
                                printf("%02x ",dev.ieee_add[l]);
                            }
                            printf("\n");
                            dev_list.device[j]=dev;
                            vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
                            start=start+SIZE_SHORT_ADD+SIZE_IEEE_ADD+2+1; //info of device 1 not used + id device 2 not used
                        }
                        break;
                    case COMMAND_DESCRIPTION:
                        printf(" ");
                        char add[SIZE_TYPE_DEVICE];
                        for(int j=0;j<SIZE_TYPE_DEVICE;j++){
                                add[j]=res[i][8+j];
                        }
                        int id = device_shortadd_compare(add);
                        if(id != -1){
                            printf("type: ");
                            for(int j=0;j<SIZE_TYPE_DEVICE;j++){
                                dev_list.device[id].type_id[j]=res[i][14+j];
                                printf("%02x ",dev_list.device[id].type_id[j]);
                            }
                            printf("\n");
                            if(dev_list.device[id].type_id[0]==0x00 && dev_list.device[id].type_id[1] ==0x00){
                                printf("Device %d not found, if it's a button press it\n",i);
                            }
                        }
                        break;                        
                    case COMMAND_ADDGROUP:
                        printf("Device add to group!\n");
                        break;
                    case COMMAND_BIND:
                        printf("Press the button, hurry up!!\n");
                        break;
                }
            }
                
        }
        vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
        //taskYIELD();
    }
    vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_flush(uart_num));
}


/************************************************ZIGBEE***********************************************/

/**
 * @brief Configuration of Zigbee module (channel,type) and start network
 * 
 */
void zigbee_config_with_pemit_join(){
    
    struct message *ptx_msg =pvPortMalloc(sizeof (struct message));
    //Set Channel
    sprintf(ptx_msg->cmd,"%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",0x01, 0x02, 0x10, 0x21, 0x02, 0x10, 0x02, 0x14, 0x2D, 0x02, 0x10, 0x02, 0x10, 0x02, 0x18, 0x02, 0x10, 0x03);
    ptx_msg->len = strlen(ptx_msg->cmd);
    printf("len : %d\n", ptx_msg->len);
            for(int i=0;i<ptx_msg->len;i++){
                printf("%02x ",ptx_msg->cmd[i]);
            }
    xQueueSend(uart_queue, (void*)ptx_msg, portMAX_DELAY);
    printf("[S] Set channel to 11\n");
    vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
    //Set Type
    //ptx_msg = pvPortMalloc(sizeof (struct message));
    sprintf(ptx_msg->cmd,"%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",0x01, 0x02, 0x10, 0x23, 0x02, 0x10, 0x02, 0x11, 0x22, 0x02, 0x10, 0x03);
    ptx_msg->len =strlen(ptx_msg->cmd);
    xQueueSend(uart_queue, (void*)ptx_msg, portMAX_DELAY);
    printf("[S] Set as Coordinator\n");
    vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
    //Start Network
    //ptx_msg =pvPortMalloc(sizeof (struct message));
    sprintf(ptx_msg->cmd,"%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",0x01, 0x02, 0x10, 0x24, 0x02, 0x10, 0x02, 0x10, 0x24, 0x03);
    ptx_msg->len =strlen(ptx_msg->cmd);
    xQueueSend(uart_queue, (void*)ptx_msg, portMAX_DELAY);
    printf("[S] Start Network\n");
    //Permit join 
    //ptx_msg =pvPortMalloc(sizeof (struct message));
    sprintf(ptx_msg->cmd,"%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",0x01, 0x02, 0x10, 0x49, 0x02, 0x10, 0x02, 0x14, 0xB0, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0x02, 0x10, 0x03);
    ptx_msg->len =strlen(ptx_msg->cmd);
    xQueueSend(uart_queue, (void*)ptx_msg, portMAX_DELAY);
    printf("[S] Permit join: If you have button press it 2sec.\n");
    vTaskDelay(6000 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
}

void vTaskZigbee( void * pvParameters )
{
    if (uart_setup() == -1){
        printf("Err during uart setup\n");
    }
    zigbee_config_with_pemit_join();
    //taskYIELD();
    while(1){
        vTaskDelay(100000 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
    }
    
}

/************************************************MAIN***********************************************/

void app_main() {
    
    /* Create the queue used to send complete struct message structures. */
    uart_queue = xQueueCreate(20, sizeof(struct message ));
    xMutexUart = xSemaphoreCreateMutex();

    BaseType_t xReturned;
    TaskHandle_t xHandle = NULL;

    /* Create the task, storing the handle. */
    xReturned = xTaskCreate(
                    vTaskZigbee,       /* Function that implements the task. */
                    "Zigbee",          /* Text name for the task. */
                    STACK_SIZE,      /* Stack size in words, not bytes. */
                    NULL,    /* Parameter passed into the task. */
                    tskIDLE_PRIORITY,/* Priority at which the task is created. */
                    &xHandle);      /* Used to pass out the created task's handle. */
    xReturned = xTaskCreate( vTaskSend, "Send", STACK_SIZE, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY, &xHandle);
    xReturned = xTaskCreate( vTaskRead, "Read", STACK_SIZE*2, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY, &xHandle); 
}
```

Comment: When using a queue with (msg) pointer items, create a queue for them accordingly. uart_queue = xQueueCreate(20, sizeof(struct message*)); (and fix the wrong comment). Also why do you lock the uart_mutex just for sending the msg in app_main ? Mutex protection is only needed to protect the UART driver calls like uart_write_bytes.

Comment: Hi, I also tried this but the result is the same, the data is good but there is a Guru Error LoadProhibited. The answer on this post  xQueue ESP32 can't send two command seems to be the natural solution, we put a copy of the structure that we recover after. Except that if I do that the values do not match.  Do you have another idea of what could be the problem please?

Comment: So the code posted here is not he code you're using ?? However, the problem is somewhere in your code since the queues are working as you probably verified using the well documented examples. There might be e.g. a stack overflow causing a memory corruption. Did you define configASSERT and configCHECK_FOR_STACK_OVERFLOW as recommened for development ? Good luck !

Comment: I edited my post with my current code and the result. I don't find on my my ESP32 these config define to have more information. I use ESP-IDF on VScode.

Comment: You define config by running the command `idf.py menuconfig` in the project root. The ESP IDF environment has to be set up. You've allocated 2048 bytes for the sender task's stack, which is a bit small (beware - ESP IDF port of FreeRTOS interprets it as bytes, not words). I'd double it just to make sure stack corruption isn't hitting you.

Comment: Which len is 54516257561 ? BTW there is an unpaired  xSemaphoreGive(xMutexUart); in vTaskSend. in zigbee_config_with_pemit_join a NULL check of pvPortMalloc is missing (along with vPortFree of the temporary buffer).
As Tarmo proposed bump the stack size (for quick testing, tune it later) to e.g. 4096 or more because your are using quite a lot stack for local data and also (s)printf function family is known as being quite stack hungry.